# Is it okay if the primary action after an operation is visible after scrolling

Tags: scrolling, actions, call-to-action, consistency, file-input

I am designing a web app which contain many different tools this particular tool has two fields one in which user uploads a single file and other where user can upload multiple files.

The problem is when the user is uploading multiple files and sees the processing of files the final action button where output is generated shifts down.

So is it okay if the user has to scroll and then click on that button because in all the other tools the output button is placed at same location and changing the position will break consistency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does pose an issue of discoverability, And users might get lost for a while.

**One way to overcome this issue is to automatically scroll to the main button, once the files are uploaded.**

You can see these patterns in long forms, where once an error is corrected in a field, the focus automatically shifts to the next erroneous field.